# Flutter: Material with only partial shadow

Tags: flutter

Consider the following fragment:

```
Material(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
  ),
  elevation: 4.0,
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 30, 24, 8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Text('foo'),
  )
)
```

This will render a drop shadow around the widget. However, I only want the shadow left/top/right, but not bottom. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove Material widget and use the BoxShadow property of Container:

```
Container(        
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 30, 24, 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  offset: Offset(0, -2),
                  spreadRadius: 1.5,
                  blurRadius: 2
                )
              ],
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('foo'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

`boxShadow` can receive an array of `BoxShadow`s. So you can have the shadow however you want:

```
Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 30, 24, 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  offset: Offset(0, -2),
                  blurRadius: 2
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  offset: Offset(-2,-1),
                  blurRadius: 2
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  offset: Offset(2, -1),
                  blurRadius: 2
                ),
              ],
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('foo'),
          ),
```

Comment: But this doesn‘t give me a nicely animated shadow when the elevation changes.

Comment: How does the elevation change? AnimatedContainer might help you but I am not sure yet. I will look into it in the morning. It's 12pm and I can barely open my eyes :).

Comment: Sorry I could not animate the container. You might want to ask another question for animating them.